# How to pre-select the Axis (x,y or z) that the mouse will be locked to with the SHIFT key

Tags: sketchup

**BACKGROUND**

I can hold the SHIFT key down to force the Move command to move along only one axis (x,y, or z)

But I have to start moving the mouse first before locking it to an axis with the **SHIFT** key.  And when I start I have to move the mouse around a bit until it starts moving along the Axis I want to lock to. so it moves the object around a bit along undesired axis.

**DESIRED BEHAVIOR**

1. Choose an object to Move.
2. Select the axis it'll move in.
3. Move the mouse (or type in a distance along that axis)
4. Object moves in that axis.

Is there a way to to pre-select the Axis before I start moving my mouse?

Answer (score 1):

Hold the the appropriate keyboard key down:

- <- left Arrow  (X axis)
- -> right Arrow (Y Axis)
- Up arrow   (Z Axis)

H/t to this great `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eP9WKUbxPAM`